# OCR recognition - gocr

Tags: ocr

I have a small problem while trying to do ocr using the tool gocr. It sometimes recognizes an o as zero and vice versa. To solve this, i tried to make it use a user specified database path. But doing that would require me to create a map for all possible characters. Is there any way in which i could tell gocr to just use the manual db for only these 2 characters??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you just put those two characters in the db.lst file, and use it along with the ocr-engine...

so long
hank